# Symfony 2.3 EntityType Add default option value

Tags: forms, symfony

I try to add a default option to an entity field in Symfony 2.3 form builder :

```
->add('destinataire','directory', array(
                                            'required' => true, 
                                            'class'=> 'MLCUserBundle:Departement',
                                            'multiple' => false,
                                            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($options) {
                                                $data = $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                                                          ->where('d.id IN (:liste)')
                                                          ->setParameter('liste',$options['listeId'])
                                                          ->orderBy('d.name', 'ASC')
                                                        ;
                                                return $data;
                                            },
                                            'empty_data'  => $all,
                                            'choices' => $all,
                                            )
           )
```

without success I need some help! thx all !

Comment: mmm I don't see any option called "default". Can you please explain more detailed or just edit your question?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo [link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/entity.html) the default option doesn't existe, I want to add some option choices in selectbox

Comment: I think, I've understood what you mean. Try to use [placeholder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder) option.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo the placeholder doesn't existe for Sf2.3

Comment: To pre-fill a form field, you'll need to set it's data: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data

If you're just trying to have a header type option (such as "--Choose one of these options--"), you can use the empty_value option: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-value